# ¿Es posible dividir el resultado de una consulta en partes, para mostrar los registros de 20 en 20?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un ajax que hace una consulta a la base de datos y me regresa unJSON con el resultado, pero a veces el resultado trae 100 o más registros, y me gustaría mostrar los resultados de 20 en 20, podría ser con un botón que diga cargar más, o ver más... No sé si exista una librería que lo haga.

mi código:

```
<script>

   $("#myTab a").on('click', function (e) {
    let index = 0;

    let year = $(this).attr("aria-controls");

    let url = "/"

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        data: {year: year, index: index
        },
        success: function(data) {

          var json = $.parseJSON(data); // dividir este resultado de 20 en 20


        },
        error: function (error) { 
            console.log(error); 
        }
    });
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: Lo suyo sería que la consulta tuviera opción de paginación. De esa manera, podrías pedir un número de resultados desde uno inicial.

Comment: gracias, voy a revisar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas mirandolo del lado que no es, es decir, esta información no la debes limitar desde el **frontend**, debes limitarla desde el **backend**, pero no incluiste que **backend** estas usando y asumo que no lo hiciste pensando que no seria necesario.

Voy a suponer que como backend usas `PHP` y como gestor de `BD` usas `MySQL` que es lo habitual.

Según esto, supongamos que tienes la siguiente consulta en ese archivo y ustas usando `PDO` para la conexión con la base de datos:

```
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE name = :name");
$query->execute([":name" => "personaX"]);
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

La variable results almacenaría el resultado de **TODAS** las coincidencias, es decir, todos los nombres que coincidan.

Una manera de limitar esto poniendo la misma consulta es usar `LIMIT` para limitar la cantidad de datos traidos desde una `BD` por una consulta `SELECT`, entonces el mismo ejemplo quedaría de la siguiente manera usando `LIMIT`:

```
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE name = :name LIMIT 20");
$query->execute([":name" => "personaX"]);
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Ese ejemplo te traera solo las primeras 20 coincidencias.

Comment: No te recomiendo cargar 100 resultados y ocultarlos, es mejor cargar los 20 que pensabas de un inicio, cargar 100 es muy pesado, te recomiendo mejor que cuando la persona quiera cargar mas resultados hacer esta misma consulta de nuevo pero anteponiéndole como condición que el indice sea mayor al ultimo obtenido (deberás enviar el ultimo indice obtenido y usarlo como condición en la consulta), de esa manera te funcionara bien (con indice me refiero a un ID).

Comment: Update. La paginación normalmente se implementa con dos parámetros más en las *request*, la página actual (`curr`) y el tamaño de ésta (`psize`). En la *query*, se deberían escapar (`SKIP`) `curr * psize` registros y limitar (`LIMIT`) `psize` registros. El *front-end* debe ser responsable de mantener esas dos variables para añadirlas a la *request* y el *back-end* se responsabiliza de calcular qué y cuántos registros trae de la base de datos. Este es el *estándar* por muchos casos donde las IDs no tienen por qué ser secuenciales (GUIDs, Hi-Lo, ...).

Comment: @VRoxa Por supuesto, gracias por la recomendación, sin embargo es solo un ejemplo, en caso de que tenga un campo numerico autoincrementable unico (ID), el cuál es muy normal hoy en día, como dices hay otras formas mas estandar de generar el mismo resultado.

Comment: El problema de aprovecharse de los valores autoincrementales tiene por contra escenarios de ordenación y filtro. Además, es bastante más óptimo el uso de `SKIP` + `LIMIT` que `WHERE` (para encontrar IDs superiores a X) + `LIMIT`. Claro que sin conocer el sistema del OP es complicado discutir sobre eso, pero por norma general y convenio, el uso de página actual y tamaño de página es el más normalizado. En cualquier caso, como digo, dependerá de cómo esté implementado el entorno del OP. Igualmente, buen post. Se me complica el uso de PHP, xd.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, utilizo Laravel... De hecho sí estaba pensando hacerlo así como dice Riven pero pensé que era más fácilhacerlo en el frontend pero no pensé en los contra... Voy a actualizar la pregunta con lo que tenía pensado hacerlo con el backend... Con ayuda de otra persona.

Comment: También esparecido a lo que me suguiere Vroxa, pero no sé como logralo.

Comment: La publiqué, tomando en cuenta que el indice primero sea cero muestra las primeras 20, luego cambia a 1 y muestra de la 21 a la 40... y así sucesivamente

Comment: Lo suyo seria de 20 en 20, es decir, la primera vez 0, la segunda 20, la tercera que hagas una consulta 40 que la condición sea que te obtenga la información usando IDs mayores a 40 almacenados en la BD y asi sucesivamente... pero temo que al ser laravel no se como ayudarte xd, la verdad nunca he usado laravel, pero pienso aprenderlo.

Comment: Ya tengo todo funcionando en el controlador, pero no se envía el valor de la variable index, o se envia en un tipo de datos diferente a int, este es el error que me muestra: "Unsupported operand types"